# Loading MEF Exports out of a folder other than the working directory with mono in linux

Tags: c#, mono, mef

I am trying to use MEF (The version that is built in mono) for a simple pluginsystem to extend my application. I followed various tutorials that are running well with Microsofts .NET framework under windows, but (same code) failing under linux(kernel 3.7.3 - gentoo) with mono-2.10.9.

I created an interface, that all Exports (my extensions) have to reference to in an external assembly:

```
namespace PlugInInterface {

    [InheritedExport]
    public interface IPlugIn {

        void Execute(); 

    }

}
```

Then I created a Hostapplication (a ConsoleApplication) that also references to the PluginInterface:

```
namespace Host {

    class MainClass {

        private static PluginHost plugins;

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            plugins = new PluginHost();
            foreach(IPlugIn plugin in plugins.plugins) {
                plugin.Execute();
            }
        }
    }


    class PluginHost{

        [ImportMany(typeof(IPlugIn))]
        public List<IPlugIn> plugins = new List<IPlugIn>();

        public PluginHost() {
            var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog("PlugIns");
            var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            container.ComposeParts(this);   
        }   
    }
}
```

And one Extension that gets compiled in the "PlugIns" subfolder of the Debug directory, where the host-application is placed:

```
namespace TestPlugin1 {
    [Export(typeof(IPlugIn))]
    public class TestPlugin1 : IPlugIn {
        public void Execute() {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, my Name is TestPlugin_Implementation1");
        }
    }
}
```

The *DirectoryCatalog* loads the PlugIn's file ("./PlugIns/TestPlugin1.dll") but it does not recognize it as an Export (a "Part") so the `plugins` list remains empty.
It works, if I put the PluginFile in the application's workingdirectory and change the DirectoryList to:
`var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog("");`

If I run the compiled version that has been compiled from the .NET compiler with mono, the PlugIn is loaded twice.

I tried to replace the *DirectoryCatalog* manually by loading the PlugIn-files with `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(...);` and then using *AssemblyCatalogs* to load all found assemblies:

```
class PluginHost{

    [ImportMany(typeof(IPlugIn))]
    public List<IPlugIn> plugins = new List<IPlugIn>();

    public PluginHost() {
        List<AssemblyCatalog> catalogs = new List<AssemblyCatalog>();
        foreach(string plfile in Directory.GetFiles("PlugIns", "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
            catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(plfile)));
        }           
        var container = new CompositionContainer(new AggregateCatalog(catalogs));
        container.ComposeParts(this);   
    }   
}
```

This works, but the same as with the compiled .NET executable: the PlugIn loads twice.

Is this a bug of mono and it's implementation of MEF, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but it looks like you're iterating through each of the files and adding a catalog based on that file. So if you are seeing it load twice, do you have two plugins?

Comment: @lan The Plugin's assembly is only loaded once, but in the _plugins_ List (within the _PluginHost_) it appears twice

Comment: Ah ok, does the Mono version not have a DirectoryCatalog? It seemed odd manually iterating through the files.

Comment: @Ian The _DirectoryCatalog_ was the first thing I tried (codeblock 2) but that did not recognize the Plugin as Export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I run the compiled version that has been compiled from the .NET
>   compiler with mono, the PlugIn is loaded twice.

This happens because although you have `IPlugIn` decorated with `InheritedExportAttribute` you also decorate the plugin with the `ExportAttribute`. The catalog will match both of these and hence export twice. You need just one of the two approaches. Either keep the `InheritedExportAttribute` and do not decorate any implementation with the `ExportAttribute` or decorate all implementations with `ExportAttribute` and remove the `InheritedExportAttribute` from the interface.

I haven't figured out why `DirectoryCatalog` cannot load the plugin assembly on Mono. On CLR is works correctly as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you! Of course this solved the problem! I'll just load the assemblies manual before using MEF then.